# If clauses: What is "likely to happen"?

Tags: clauses, if

I learned that there are three if-clauses:

1. if + simple present, will-future: stuff that is highly likely to happen
2. if + simple past, conditional I: stuff that is not so likely to happen
3. if + past perfect, conditional II: stuff that is impossible

I want to ask you, which countries you will/would like to visit, if there are/where no constraints.

So should I use if-clause I or II? I'm confused, because clause I sounds wrong to me, because I'm not asking for concrete plans of visiting a country, but more theoretically. However when I try to follow the rule, it's highly possible that you will visit those countries somewhere in the future. Maybe not this or next year, but you are not 80yo, so if you like, you can do it.... maybe I make things too complex, I'm confused.

So, what exactly is "highly likely" in regard to if-clause I vs II? What's the difference between

> Which countries you want to visit if you can choose?

and

> Which countries you would like to visit if you could choose?

and is the last one even correct or do I need to write

> Which countries you liked to visit if you could choose?

?

Comment: Highly likely: "If you go out in the rain, you will get wet."

Comment: 100% certain: "Were you to stop breathing, you would die".

Comment: I don't understand how there can be any uncertainty at all about the addressee being able to at least ***choose*** which countries he  would ***like*** to visit, regardless of how likely or unlikely it might be that he could actually ***go*** to any of those countries.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of your example sentences are grammatically incorrect.  This makes it a little hard to say "what the difference is".  A grammatically correct, idiomatic version might be **Which countries would you like to visit if you could choose?**

Comment: You've almost got the answer already. You know when to use each type of "if"-clause, so which one do you think applies to the situation where you can visit any country in the world with no constraints? Is that likely, unlikely, or impossible?

Comment: It's worth noting that you have the names wrong. Form 1 is part of what's commonly called "first conditional", form 2 is part of "second conditional", and form 3 is part of "third conditional". There are also many more ways to make an "if"-clause, not just those three forms.

Comment: Further, the third one is for things that are impossible because the condition is not true, and it's in the past, so cannot be changed